# How to get accessToken from Kaizala API

Tags: javascript, json, kaizala

I'm trying to generate an access token from Microsoft Kaizala API following the information provided by [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/kaizala/connectors/tokens)

I already created a connector and I have the correct credentials:

```
-applicationId
-applicationSecret
-refreshToken
```

And make a `GET` request from the url: https://api.kaiza.la/v1/accessToken via Postman with the correct headers provided by my connector.

But I always get a 200 response but with a body like this:

> This page does not exist. This page never existed. © 2016 Microsoft
>   Corporation. All rights reserved.

Instead of getting the JSON response, I really appreciate your help.

Thank You!

Comment: The answer is on the first comment, by the way thanks to all stackoverflow community.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue turns out after some debugging I replaced the access token url https://api.kaiza.la/v1/accessToken by https://kms2.kaiza.la/v1/accessToken and I got my access token.

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thank You so much alaa bitar that really helped me, I tried with this url https://kms2.kaiza.la/v1/accessToken and didn´t work but i tried with another url https://kms1.kaiza.la/v1/accessToken and it works, thank You for the idea!

Comment: The documentation on MS Developer needs to be update to reflect this.